# Determine target ISA extensions of binary file in Linux (library or executable)

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, executable, cpu-architecture, instruction-set

We have an issue related to a Java application running under a (rather old) FC3 on an Advantech POS board with a Via C3 processor. The java application has several compiled shared libs that are accessed via JNI.

Via C3 processor is supposed to be i686 compatible. Some time ago after installing Ubuntu 6.10 on a MiniItx board with the same processor, I found out that the previous statement is not 100% true. The Ubuntu kernel hanged on startup due to the lack of some specific and optional instructions of the i686 set in the C3 processor. These instructions missing in C3 implementation of i686 set are used by default by GCC compiler when using i686 optimizations. The solution, in this case, was to go with an i386 compiled version of Ubuntu distribution.

The base problem with the Java application is that the FC3 distribution was installed on the HD by cloning from an image of the HD of another PC, this time an Intel P4. Afterwards, the distribution needed some hacking to have it running such as replacing some packages (such as the kernel one) with the i386 compiled version.

The problem is that after working for a while the system completely hangs without a trace. I am afraid that some i686 code is left somewhere in the system and could be executed randomly at any time (for example after recovering from suspend mode or something like that).

My question is:

- Is there any tool or way to find out at what specific architecture extensions a binary file (executable or library) requires? `file` does not give enough information.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you need a tool that checks every instruction, to determine exactly which set it belongs to. Is there even an offical name for the specific set of instructions implemented by the C3 processor? If not, it's even hairier.

A quick'n'dirty variant might be to do a raw search in the file, if you can determine the bit pattern of the disallowed instructions. Just test for them directly, could be done by a simple `objdump | grep` chain, for instance.

Comment: objdump -d    should get you an ASM representation you can then just grep for bad opcodes.

Comment: I think I will go the way you propose. I only need to find out how to decompile vmlinuz (I can not be sure if kernel itself is i386 or i686 version).

Comment: +1. It isn't much of a help in my case, but I really love this hacky way!

Comment: I use this command to extract the target file architecture informartion... `objdump -x <file> | grep Architektur: | cut --delimiter=" " -f 2 | cut --delimiter="," -f 1`

Answer (score 113):

The unix.linux `file` command is great for this. It can generally detect the target architecture and operating system for a given binary (and has been maintained on and off since 1973. wow!)

Of course, if you're not running under unix/linux - you're a bit stuck.  I'm currently trying to find a java based port that I can call at runtime.. but no such luck.

The unix `file` command gives information like this:

```
hex: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.4.17, not stripped
```

More detailed information about the details of the architecture are hinted at with the (unix) `objdump -f <fileName>` command which returns:

```
architecture: arm, flags 0x00000112:
EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED
start address 0x0000876c
```

This executable was compiled by a gcc cross compiler (compiled on an i86 machine for the ARM processor as a target)

Comment: The question specifically asks to go beyond **file** but I came here on the basis of the title, and **file** is exactly what I wanted. So it's questionable if this is really a good answer, because it didn't answer the actual qeustion, but it did answer mine and apparently aaronstacy's too!

Comment: (I added some info about (unix) 'objdump -f' command that goes beyond the 'file' command.  Regrettably I don't know what the bits in the 'flags' mean -- probably need to search the gcc code for that.   (or use them to compare the setting on various target machines))

Comment: When I try the last one, I get `objdump: Unknown command line argument '-f'.  Try: 'objdump -help'`

Answer (score 31):

In my case the information provided by `file` and `objdump` wasn't enough, neither was `grep` of any help.

What worked though is: `readelf -a -W`. It outputs a lot of info. The arch related information resides in the very beginning and the very end. Example:

```hs
λ readelf -aW ./my_binary
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x83f8
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          2388 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000202, has entry point, Version5 EABI, soft-float ABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         8
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         31
  Section header string table index: 28
[…]
Displaying notes found at file offset 0x00000148 with length 0x00000020:
  Owner                 Data size   Description
  GNU                  0x00000010   NT_GNU_ABI_TAG (ABI version tag)
    OS: Linux, ABI: 2.6.16
Attribute Section: aeabi
File Attributes
  Tag_CPU_name: "7-A"
  Tag_CPU_arch: v7
  Tag_CPU_arch_profile: Application
  Tag_ARM_ISA_use: Yes
  Tag_THUMB_ISA_use: Thumb-2
  Tag_FP_arch: VFPv3
  Tag_Advanced_SIMD_arch: NEONv1
  Tag_ABI_PCS_wchar_t: 4
  Tag_ABI_FP_rounding: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_denormal: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_exceptions: Needed
  Tag_ABI_FP_number_model: IEEE 754
  Tag_ABI_align_needed: 8-byte
  Tag_ABI_align_preserved: 8-byte, except leaf SP
  Tag_ABI_enum_size: int
  Tag_ABI_HardFP_use: SP and DP
  Tag_CPU_unaligned_access: v6
```

Comment: Disclaimer: this only works if you already know the file is an ELF file. Mach-O binaries (that run on iPhones and Macbooks) are an example of a binary format that isn't ELF.

Comment: @ryanrhee well, if you not yet knows whether it ELF or no, then after you ran the command you will surely know ☺

Comment: I you want just the architecture information, you can use `readelf -A`

Answer (score 5):

To answer the ambiguity of whether a Via C3 is a i686 class processor: It's not, it's an i586 class processor.

Cyrix never produced a true 686 class processor, despite their marketing claims with the 6x86MX and MII parts. Among other missing instructions, two important ones they didn't have were CMPXCHG8b and CPUID, which were required to run Windows XP and beyond.

National Semiconductor, AMD and VIA have all produced CPU designs based on the Cyrix 5x86/6x86 core (NxP MediaGX, AMD Geode, VIA C3/C7, VIA Corefusion, etc.) which have resulted in oddball designs where you have a 586 class processor with SSE1/2/3 instruction sets.

My recommendation if you come across any of the CPUs listed above and it's not for a vintage computer project (ie. Windows 98SE and prior) then run screaming away from it. You'll be stuck on slow i386/486 Linux or have to recompile all of your software with Cyrix specific optimizations.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding upon @Hi-Angel's answer I found an easy way to check the bit width of a static library:

```
readelf -a -W libsomefile.a | grep Class: | sort | uniq
```

Where `libsomefile.a` is my static library.  Should work for other ELF files as well.

Answer (score 3):

Quickest thing to find architecture would be to execute:

```
objdump -f testFile | grep architecture
```

This works even for binary.

Comment: I get `objdump: Unknown command line argument '-f'.  Try: 'objdump -help'`

Comment: this is working on my side with -f, or -x