# How do I determine the target architecture of static library (.a) on Mac OS X?

Tags: iphone, macos, linker, bsd, universal-binary

I'm interested in verifying if a given iPhone static library has been built for ARM or Intel.

It's more curiosity than anything. Is there some kind of Mac OS X or BSD specific tool to do this? This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267941/determine-target-architecture-of-binary-file-in-linux-library-or-executable) gives an example in Linux.

Answer (score 288, accepted):

Another option is `lipo`; its output is brief and more readable than `otool`'s.

An example:

```
% lipo -info /usr/lib/libiodbc.a 
Architectures in the fat file: /usr/lib/libiodbc.a are: x86_64 i386 ppc
% lipo -info libnonfatarchive.a
input file libnonfatarchive.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: libnonfatarchive.a is architecture: i386
%
```

Comment: Just verified this with an old PJSIP .a file.  armv7.  Thanks.

Comment: How can I check minimum iOS version of a target architecture (.a) ?

Answer (score 73):

`file` will probably tell you. `otool` certainly should be able to. But I'd try `file` first,
e.g.

```
logan:/Users/logan% file d2
d2: Mach-O executable ppc
```

Example with archive:

```
logan:/Users/logan% file /usr/lib/libMallocDebug.a
/usr/lib/libMallocDebug.a: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/lib/libMallocDebug.a (for architecture i386):      current ar archive random library
/usr/lib/libMallocDebug.a (for architecture ppc):       current ar archive
```

Comment: In my experience `file` often fails.

Comment: See the answer about lipo further down, always works.

Comment: I've noticed that if the .a is is not ranlib'd, file sometimes reports less information.

Comment: Now in 2015 you should use lipo. See the answer below.

Comment: Unfortunately this hasn't worked for several OS versions.

Answer (score 65):

As mentioned earlier, `file` does not always work. `otool -hv -arch all` is probably the closest thing that is guaranteed to work - it gives architecture information for every single object file in the library.

Example:

```
% otool -hv /sw/lib/libfftw3.a
Archive : /sw/lib/libfftw3.a
/sw/lib/libfftw3.a(align.o):
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
MH_MAGIC_64  X86_64        ALL  0x00      OBJECT     3        336 SUBSECTIONS_VIA_SYMBOLS
/sw/lib/libfftw3.a(alloc.o):
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
MH_MAGIC_64  X86_64        ALL  0x00      OBJECT     3        416 SUBSECTIONS_VIA_SYMBOLS
...
```

Comment: Just to add to this answer, I prefer otool over file or lipo. I tried file, lipo and otool with an iOS fat library and otool was the only one that showed me that it contained files for i386 (iPhone Simulator) and for armv6, armv7 and armv7s (iPhone OS).

Comment: NOTE: if you want to check whether your library is fat or not, you want to use "otool -arch all"; otherwise, it will report only one architecture per .o file. For a quick overview of the architectures in your .a, "otool -f"

Answer (score 7):

If anyone comes here looking for answers about how to tell whether a library (or the object files in it) are intended for Mac Catalyst, use `otool -l` to dump the load commands. Find the LC_BUILD_VERSION section for any object. Mac Catalyst is identified by `platform 6` rather than `platform 1`.

Answer (score 6):

This bash script will help you programmatically get a list of architectures into a variable.

list_archs.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
lipo -info $1 | sed -En -e 's/^(Non-|Architectures in the )fat file: .+( is architecture| are): (.*)$/\3/p'
```

Usage example:

```
./list_archs.sh /usr/lib/libc.dylib
x86_64 i386
```

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, I've found `objdump` can work well.  As an example, in my environment I build library archives with vxWorks and need to link those into other projects.  To test whether the archive is the correct architecture, I could do something like the following (bash syntax):

```
if [ "$(objdumpsparc -a ${ARCHIVE_FILE} 2>&1 | ggrep -cvP 'elf32-sparc-vxworks')" -ne "0" ]; then
  echo "Cannot build with ${ARCHIVE_FILE}, it contains one or more non-sparc components"
fi;
```

This example isn't precisely correct, because some lines DO show up that don't say elf32-sparc-vxworks, but it's easy enough to adapt this.

One nice benefit of this is that `objdump`, or a similarly named variant, is installed on most *nix operating systems, whereas tools suggested in other responses aren't.

*edit* It just occurred to me the OP was asking on OSX.  My apologies.

Comment: To use `objdump` you can install the GNU Binutils via MacPorts. To see all available architectures just execute `port search binutils`. The tools for native development are prefixed to avoid conflicts (e.g. `gobjdump` instead of `objdump`). You might want to create an alias for convenience.