# Issue Running Sample In Mac Pro X86_64 Of V8 Engine?

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

Recently, I have a try to build and run sample hello world program of google v8.
My xcode version is 4.0.2GA, x86_64.

The guide's link: [get Started](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/get_started.html)

But when run the command:
g++ -Iinclude hello_world.cpp -o hello_world libv8.a -lpthread

The errors show:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file libv8.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"v8::Context::Enter()", referenced from:
      v8::Context::Scope::Scope(v8::Handle<v8::Context>)in ccJsmYlc.o
  "v8::V8::DisposeGlobal(v8::internal::Object**)", referenced from:
      v8::Persistent<v8::Context>::Dispose()      in ccJsmYlc.o
  "v8::Context::Exit()", referenced from:
      v8::Context::Scope::~Scope()in ccJsmYlc.o
  "v8::HandleScope::HandleScope()", referenced from:
      _main in ccJsmYlc.o
  "v8::Context::New(v8::ExtensionConfiguration*, v8::Handle<v8::ObjectTemplate>, v8::Handle<v8::Value>)", referenced from:
      _main in ccJsmYlc.o
  "v8::String::New(char const*, int)", referenced from:
      _main in ccJsmYlc.o
  "v8::Script::Compile(v8::Handle<v8::String>, v8::ScriptOrigin*, v8::ScriptData*, v8::Handle<v8::String>)", referenced from:
      _main in ccJsmYlc.o
  "v8::Script::Run()", referenced from:
      _main in ccJsmYlc.o
  "v8::String::AsciiValue::AsciiValue(v8::Handle<v8::Value>)", referenced from:
      _main in ccJsmYlc.o
  "v8::String::AsciiValue::~AsciiValue()", referenced from:
      _main in ccJsmYlc.o
  "v8::HandleScope::~HandleScope()", referenced from:
      _main in ccJsmYlc.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be obvious you are trying to link with a .a that was build for another architecture. Check out [How do I determine the target architecture of static library (.a) on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085137/how-do-i-determine-the-target-architecture-of-static-library-a-on-mac-os-x) to learn how to check the target architecture of that .a.  Once you know that you can either retarget you project, or create a new libv8.a for the x86_64 architecture.

Comment: I check the the default is a32, then I rebuild with scons arch=x64, works well. Thanks!