# What `xcodebuild` commands are executed when I run Product -> Archive in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I'm trying to build an IOS app from the command line instead of through Xcode it's been an uphill struggle. My project builds fine in Xcode by going to Product -> Archive, but when I try to do what I think is the same thing in the Terminal with `xcodebuild`, it fails due to some missing header files.

How do I find out what actually happens when I click Archive?

Alternatively, if anyone can spot where my error is, the command I think should be working is:

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -scheme MyApp -configuration Beta -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath <path to xcarchive file> archive
```

Comment: ever get a solution that works?

Answer (score 6):

Hi I have a guess because I could not find the actual documentation. I have a small script that works for deployment directly on the App Store using my private keys. 
I'm sharing with you if it can helps, I'm asking you to accept the answer.

```
#clean and build
xcodebuild -workspace ./my-app.xcworkspace/ -scheme my-app -sdk iphonesimulator12.0 clean # analyze
xcodebuild -workspace ./my-app.xcworkspace/ -scheme my-app -destination generic/platform=iOS build

#archive
xcodebuild -workspace ./my-app.xcworkspace/ -scheme my-app -sdk iphoneos -configuration AppStoreDistribution archive -archivePath $PWD/build/my-app.xcarchive

# create build ipa
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $PWD/build/my-app.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist -exportPath $PWD/build

# /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Support/altool
# upload app for testflight
export USERNAME=myusername
export PASSWORD=mypassword
# password is generated at appleid.apple.com
cd build
altool --upload-app -f "my-app.ipa" -u $USERNAME -p $PASSWORD
```

## References

1. [How do I determine the target architecture of static library (.a) on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085137/how-do-i-determine-the-target-architecture-of-static-library-a-on-mac-os-x)
2. https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/13401
3. https://medium.com/xcblog/xcodebuild-deploy-ios-app-from-command-line-c6defff0d8b8

You mentioned that your app fails because of header files, I'm suggesting that you check this out because it can be a pain in the ... sometimes. By the way my app has some native headers too.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, that's really useful! Unfortunately your version of the archive command doesn't work either but I'll check out the links you posted.