# How to get cpu instruction set from shared libraray java android

Tags: java, android

Well my question is straight forward,
for example i know the header might have all the required information,what i am looking is that how can i get the instruction set the  shared library is having

For example ,i have file present in "/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/tmp/lib.so

now ,how can i get that the libaray is for Armv7,or x86,mips or x86_64 or mips64 or armeabi ?

any way something like

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(libHeader);
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
```

and any specific byte at location which tells us the architecture or instruction set

i actually want to know it from android application only.
Thanks

Comment: it won't be easy, i presume... http://stackoverflow.com/a/2902650/2657100

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/24577159/4271923 from the same question is even more on the spot, plus this: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/elf-object-file-format  ... should be enough to code some initial quick-hack code to decide the `.so` platform.

Comment: well i got but i am unable to know how to differ armeabi and armeabi-v7  because both has same header,otherwise all other are different